# wordpress multisite... collect all posts on main blog - exclude category?

Tags: categories, multisite

hey guys,
I'm using the sitewide tags Multisite plugin on my wordpress setup. I'm collecting all blogposts of multiple subblogs on my mainblog.

Any idea how I could manage to exclude a certain category from this collection?
e.g. If a user is writing a blogpost on a subblog and is adding it to the category "private" the mainblog should not show this post!

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to encourage users to instead use the 'Post Visibility' option in the main publishing actions box on the post edit screen. Rather than filing private posts in a category, the user can simply set a post to private. Unless by 'private' you mean private to their individual blog but still public...

Comment: With private I mean only visible to the subblog! :) The category name doesn't have to be "private" could be something else. I just need a way to allow subblog authors to decided wheter a post is displayed on the mainblog. It should be the normal case (that's why I'm using sitewide tags) but there should be some option to be able to choose wheter it's posted to the mainblog or not!

Comment: Alright, I'm on it for ya! Stay tuned.

Comment: Yeah, I can't get anywhere with this. It looks like it is something you'll have to request of the developers to include. They already have filters built in to allow and disallow post types and taxonomies, what you need is something similar to that, but disallow a specific term from a taxonomy.

Comment: ok, thanks anyway. I'll may ask for that feature to be included!